# Template variable not parsing

Tags: templates, variable, parse

We have a custom third-party module called qo5. All of our controllers are in there.

I have a template that I need to pass a variable from a PHP function to.

```
{exp:qo5 action="deal/getDealCode"}
    <span>Test: {default_combo_override}</span>
{/exp:qo5}
```

The `deal/getDealCode` function looks like this:

```
public function getDealCode() {
        $deal_id = $this->EE->input->post('deal_id');
        $deal_code = $_SESSION['order']['coupons'][$deal_id]['code'];
        error_log("deal code: " . $deal_code);

        if($deal_code == 'GARLICPARM') {
                $data['default_combo_override'] = 'AT';
                error_log("Data");
                error_log(print_r($data, 1));
                return $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables($this->EE->TMPL->tagdata, $data);
            }
    }
```

I know it's being called; the error log is executing and displaying the correct data. But the span value for `default_combo_override` is not being populated.

What am I missing here? We use similar functionality all over the place, and it works everywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array that you're passing to `parse_variables` is incorrectly structured - it needs to be one level deeper.

You can fix this either by wrapping it in an array:

```
return $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables($this->EE->TMPL->tagdata, array($data));
```

Or using `parse_variables_row` instead:

```
return $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables_row($this->EE->TMPL->tagdata, $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the parsed_variable into a new variable and then returning that?

```
$output = $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables($this->EE->TMPL->tagdata, $data);
return $output ;
```